# Androidタブレットでの実機デバッグができない

Tags: android-studio

androidstudioでスマホでは実行できるのにタブレットだと実行できないのですが、理由がわからないので、わかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

以下エラーコード

---

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes


Error:1 error; aborting


Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
```

Comment: PC、スマホ、タブレットそれぞれのOSとAndroidStudioのバージョンは何でしょうか

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14175475664

Answer (score 1):

できるかどうかわかりませんが…
build.gradle(mobile)にMultidexを有効にする旨を記載
AndroidManifest.xmlにMultiDexApplicationであることを記載

build.gradle(mobile)

```
        defaultConfig {
　 ..
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dependencies {
  　 ..
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
         <application
   　 ..
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
 　 ..
</application>
```

Comment: 補足しますが、この回答は「原因がdex内のメソッド超過であった場合」にのみ有効な対策です。